# Not able to Store Boolean in Spring Reactive Redis Cache

Tags: java, caching, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-redis

```
" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot serialize value of type class java.lang.Boolean without a serializer
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:287) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultReactiveHashOperations.rawHashValue(DefaultReactiveHashOperations.java:286) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
```

I am getting this exception while storing a Boolean.

My redis config:

```
ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplateGeneric(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory) {
    GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer valueSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Object> builder =
            RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
    RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context = builder.value(valueSerializer).build();
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory, context);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to set serializer in the hashValue as well while building the context..

```
RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context = builder.value(valueSerializer).hashValue(valueSerializer).build();
```